# Поддержка разрядности приложения разными системами

Tags: c++

Моему приложению нужна поддержка как x32 систем так и x64. В интернете мне удалось найти статью в которой сказано что x64 системы поддерживают запуск x32 битных приложений. Тогда встаёт вопрос, стоит ли вообще делать 2 версии программы для двух систем, или можно обойтись одной x32?

Comment: Ну, если вам не нужна адресация большого количества памяти, то почему бы и нет?...

Comment: Прекрасно, спасибо. А инжект 64 битных библиотек при помощи 32 битного приложения будет работать?

Comment: @AugustVishnevsky 32-х битная программа может работать в 64-х разрядной среде, наоборот нет.

Comment: @Joker Я понял про программу, сейчас речь идёт про DLL. Если я делаю инжект x64 библиотеки из x32 приложения куда-нибудь, всё по идее будет в порядке?

Comment: @AugustVishnevsky Суда по всему, речь идёт о Windows, поэтому надо проверить есть ли у неё на этот счёт ограничения, мне это не известно.

Comment: @AugustVishnevsky 32 битное приложение не сможет открыть 64 библиотеку ни через dlopen ни линковкой

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Стоит делать, потому что будущее за 64-разрядными системами, и уже сейчас идёт отказ от поддержки 32-разрядных, так что однажды может оказаться что 32-разрядную программу будет проблематично запустить. Это хорошо видно на примере Linux'а, где поддержка 32-разрадной среды постепенно сдувается.
К тому же 32-разрядное приложение запущенное в 64-разрядной среде не получит преимуществ наличия дополнительных регистров процессора, что может сказаться на скорости работы.